# Table with multirow & multicolumn, spacing problems

Tags: tables, spacing, multirow

The following table is aesthetically sub-optiomal.

[image]

The vertical spacing between paragraph rows is bigger than the one between table rows, e.g. second and third lines.

The horizontal size is hard-coded (two different lengths, i.e. column 2+3, and 3 only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{lcp{0.75\textwidth}}
\texttt{aaaaaaaaa} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{Blah blah blah
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.}}\\
\texttt{bbbbbbb} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{Blah blah blah
  blah blah blah blah blah blah.}}\\
\texttt{ccccccccccc} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{Blah blah
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.}}\\
\texttt{ddddddddd} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{Blah blah blah
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.}}\\
\texttt{eeeeeeeee} & \rdelim\}{2}{0pt} & \multirow{2}{*}{%
  \parbox[t]{0.75\textwidth}{Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
  blah blah.}}\\
\texttt{ffffffff} & & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to do this? How do I solve the problems mentioned above?

(There are multiple other questions about `multirow` and `multicolumn` but I did not find one that seemed identical.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bigdelim}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily}lp{0.75\textwidth}}
aaaaaaaaa   & Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
bbbbbbb     & Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
ccccccccccc & Blah blah   blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
ddddddddd   & Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
eeeeeeeee   &\rdelim\}{2}{0.75\textwidth}[\parbox{\dimexpr 0.75\textwidth-9pt}{Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
  blah blah.}] \\
ffffffff    &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Here's a slightly more automatic aolution that almost perfectly fits into the textwidth, but still requires you to explicitly set the width of the first column according to its widest entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bigdelim}

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\myfirstcol}
\newlength{\mysecondcol}
\newlength{\mythirdcol}
\setlength{\myfirstcol}{\widthof{\texttt{ccccccccccc}}}
\setlength{\mysecondcol}{\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-\myfirstcol}
\setlength{\mythirdcol}{\mysecondcol-\widthof{$\Bigg\}$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily}wl{\myfirstcol}p{\mysecondcol}}
aaaaaaaaa   & Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
bbbbbbb     & Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
ccccccccccc & Blah blah   blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
ddddddddd   & Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
eeeeeeeee   &\rdelim\}{2}{\mysecondcol}[\parbox{\mythirdcol}{Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
  blah blah.}] \\
ffffffff    &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution (and a simpler code) with `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l@{\,}c@{}X@{}}
\texttt{aaaaaaaaa} & & Blah blah blah
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
\texttt{bbbbbbb} & & Blah blah blah
  blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
\texttt{ccccccccccc} & & Blah blah
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
\texttt{ddddddddd} & & Blah blah blah
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
\texttt{eeeeeeeee} & & \\
\texttt{ffffffff} & \llap{\rdelim\}{-1.6}{*}}\enspace& \multirow{-1.6}{=}{Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added*: A way to obtain what you want, as to the alignment of the brace:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l@{\,}X@{}}
    \texttt{aaaaaaaaa} & Blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
    \texttt{bbbbbbb} & Blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
    \texttt{ccccccccccc} & Blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
    \texttt{ddddddddd} & Blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
    \texttt{eeeeeeeee} & \\
    \texttt{ffffffff} & \rdelim\}{-1.6}{*}[\,\parbox{0.97\hsize}{Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.}]
    \end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Comment: Well the bracket is wrong now.

Comment: I rarely play with `arraystretch`n as it destroys the vertical centring of rows contents. There are better way with `cellspace`, but here I thought  `\extrarowheight` was enough.

Comment: In my opinion, it looks better as I did it (that  may depend on the real contents of the table).

Comment: Of course , you may modify the parameters, and you may insert  the big delimiter at the beginning of the last column, which would reduce the table preamble to `{lX}`. But typographically, I think it's an error.

Comment: The brace was  actually too close to  `ddd…` – unless I've misunderstood what it should cover.

Comment: The idea is that `eee`... and `fff`... have the same right-most column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119475/discussion-between-bernard-and-tomas-by).

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 5.11 2021-02-22). The size of the brace is computed automatically from the contens of the cell (no manual adjustment needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{bigdelim}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\ttfamily}lp{0.75\textwidth}}
aaaaaaaaa   & Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
bbbbbbb     & Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
ccccccccccc & Blah blah   blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
ddddddddd   & Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\\
eeeeee      & \multirow{2}{=}{\advance \leftskip by 1 em Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.} \\
ffffffff    &  \\
\CodeAfter \SubMatrix{.}{5-1}{6-1}\}[right-xshift=2\tabcolsep]
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]